# Law of total conditional probability

Tags: probability

Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be events. It feels intuitive to me that
\begin{equation}
Pr(A \mid B) = Pr(A \mid C)Pr(C \mid B) + Pr(A \mid \bar C) Pr(\bar C \mid B)
\end{equation}

But is that true at all? If so, I don't immediately see how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is true is $$\Pr(A \mid B) = \Pr(A \mid C,B)\,\Pr(C \mid B) + \Pr(A \mid \bar C, B)\, \Pr(\bar C \mid B)$$ but that is not quite what you have

For a counterexample to $\Pr(A \mid B) = \Pr(A \mid C)\,\Pr(C \mid B) + \Pr(A \mid \bar C)\, \Pr(\bar C \mid B)$, consider the equally likely events

```
A    B    C
1    1    0 
1    0    1
0    1    0
0    1    1
1    0    0
```

giving

- $\Pr(A \mid B) = \frac13$
- $\Pr(A \mid C) = \frac12$
- $\Pr(C \mid B) = \frac13$
- $\Pr(A \mid \bar C) = \frac23$
- $\Pr(\bar C \mid B) =\frac23$

and $\frac13 \not= \frac12 \times \frac13 + \frac23 \times \frac23$

while

- $\Pr(A \mid C,B) = 0$
- $\Pr(A \mid \bar C, B) = \frac12$

and my restatement would then give $\frac13 = 0 \times \frac13 + \frac12 \times \frac23$ correctly

Comment: Thanks! It made sense that I was missing something :)

Answer (score 1):

That is not quite right. It should be 
$$
P(A|B)=P(A|C\cap B)P(C|B)+P(A|\overline C\cap B)P(\overline C|B)
$$
This can be proved by replacing each instance of $P(E|F)$ with $P(E\cap F)/P(F)$, then simplifying.